# Wagtail video embed fails for some YouTube URLs but not others

Tags: youtube, wagtail, oembed

I have a Wagtail 2.3 instance, and am embedding videos in templates from a variety of sources. A small portion of YouTube video URLs fail when attempting to embed, despite appearing to allow embedding. If I call `get_embed` directly, I see a HTTP 401 Unauthorized error and `get_embed` returns None. If I use the video embed widget on the page editor, for these URLs it fails with "Cannot find an embed for this URL."

Manually embedding any of these videos with an iframe from the "Share" frame options on these videos works fine.

An example of a video that is failing: https://youtu.be/rCvKr6nsS3w

Has anyone experienced similar with Wagtail video embedding or oembed generally? Does anyone know why these particular videos would be failing?

Answer (score 1):

The example video https://youtu.be/rCvKr6nsS3w has embedding disabled by the uploader - you can confirm this from the video page by clicking Share then Embed.

Comment: When I click "Share > Embed" on that video, I get given iframe embed code that, when I place it in a webpage, successfully displays that video. Are you seeing "Embedding disabled"?